# Content stolen/scrubbed from SE

Tags: discussion

Almost immediately after I answered my own [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/281122/219455)
google offered it as a search result, but from a totally different site and under a strange name "Jessica Alba": https://www.onooks.com/java-stored-procedure-or-user-defined-function-could-not-call-java-method/

Is SE aware of this kind of scrubbing? Is this allowed under SE terms?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens quite frequently, and is completely in accordance with the terms of use of the Stack Exchange sites assuming the scraper follows the license terms.

There is a [question and answer concerning scrapers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do) on the StackExchange meta site.

I'm not a lawyer, but it looks like they might be in violation of the spirit of the license, if not the letter, by the fact that they don't seem to be giving proper attribution.

From the meta.se question linked above:

> Please [contact us](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) directly using the on-site form. Select the "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution" option from the drop-down, and provide as much information as possible. Even if you are reporting an entire site that is scraping many questions, please provide an example of a question on their site and the corresponding question on our site, as well as any Google search terms you used that led you to finding this site. Any other information you might have can be included in the free-form text box.